# Generate 5 Unique Random Numbers in min and max range and sort in Ascending Order in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to this group and this is my first post.

### Can some one please help me to generate 5 Unique numbers in min and max range and then sort them in ascending order using groovy.
note: I am doing this in soapui.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
import java.util.Random

Random r = new Random();
def i

List random_num

for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    random_num(i) = r.nextInt(9+2)
    if(i>0)
    {
        if(random_num[i]==random_num[i-1])
        random_num[i] = r.nextInt(9+2)
    }
}

    random_num.sort() ;
    log.info random_num
```

---

thank you

Comment: How for have you got? Which bit are you stuck on

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. i am using the code as shown in the main post, i have posted the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part about *rand between a min and max* can be found
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/3181392).

For the other constraints:

- Unique values: use a `Set` for your result
- Ascending order: use a **sorted `Set`**

E.g.:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

def n = 5
def min = 5
def max = 42

def result = new TreeSet()

while (result.size()<n) {
    result << ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1)
}

println result
// → [7, 8, 29, 37, 42]
```

Note: make sure `max - min > n`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very Java-ish. Groovy was developed, partly to eliminate a lot of the Java ceremony.

This is what I use to generate a random number:

```
def randNum(minSize, maxSize) {
    return Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(maxSize + 1 - minSize) + minSize)
}
```

You can call that five times, collect the results in a list, and sort the list. To call a routine, you can use:

```
5.times {randNum(minSize, maxSize)}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the info. I need to get the unique numbers, will this return duplicate values if i run for 5 times?

 As i am new to the groovy, i am trying to declare the list, but some how i am failed. the code that i am using from your message is as below:

def randNum(minSize, maxSize) 
{

    return Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(maxSize + 1 - minSize) + minSize)

}

def list = [5]

list = 5.times {randNum(1, 55)}

log.info list

could you pls help me how to get the values to the list

Comment: Hi, some how i succeeded to add the numbers to the list using below: 

def randNum(minSize, maxSize) {
    return Math.abs(new Random().nextInt(maxSize + 1 - minSize) + minSize)
}
def list = []
for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
 list.add(randNum(1, 55))
}

log.info list
list.sort()
log.info list

but pls help me on the duplications check

Comment: @SudeekshaHoney just check if a value is already in the list before adding it

Comment: Hi @ou_ryperd, yes, this is generating the unique numbers.... thank you